# How to do subscription for android app for every one year

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    payWithPaypal();
}


private void payWithPaypal() 

{
    PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();

    BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(10);

    newPayment.setSubtotal(bigDecimal);

    newPayment.setCurrencyType(Currency.getInstance(Locale.US));

//  newPayment.setRecipient("testandroid366-facilitator@gmail.com");

    newPayment.setRecipient("b.umamaheshwar-facilitator@gmail.com ");

    newPayment.setMerchantName("Testing Android");


      PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
      if(pp==null)
         pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284XXXXXXXXXX", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
```

//Call the paypal activity

```
 Intent paypalIntent = pp.checkout(newPayment, this);
 this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);

}
```

here i am using paypal to achieve answer for my above question,i am able to make payment. i am planning to make a background service for getting app installed date and for executing paywithpaypal() after one year.i am not getting how to do it,any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a read-only preference value.
Define it like this in the .xml file:

```
<EditTextPreference 
    android:summary="Date of your last subscription"
    android:defaultValue="N/A"
    android:title="Subscription date"
    android:key="prefSubscription"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

And use it like this in your code:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("prefSubscription","");
```

And then you have to think about the rest of your code. Basically you have two options:

- Get the current date via `Calendar` class then convert both dates to a long value and subtract the difference to see if it's greater than 365 days.
- Convert the preference value to date, add another year to it and compare it with the current date.

FYI, you initialize the Calendar object this way:

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```